calculations in expression for value in Report Viewer/Rdlc but Result do not match in VB.NET
I'm Trying to calculations in expression for value in Report Viewer/Rdlc but Result do not match in VB.NET
is there anything wrong with my code, please guide me
or something is wrong in the expression calculation
I use an expression like this:
=SUM(Fields!UnitPrice.Value * Fields!Quantity.Value - Fields!Discount.Value)-(Parameters!pDiscountTotal.Value+Parameters!pReturTotal.Value)

Thanks
Public Class Order
        Public Property CustomerName As String
        Public Property DiscountTotal As Integer
        Public Property ReturTotal As Integer
        Public Property OrderDetails As List(Of OrderDetail)
    End Class
    Public Class OrderDetail
        Public Property ProductName As String
        Public Property UnitPrice As Integer
        Public Property Quantity As Integer
        Public Property Discount As Integer
    End Class
    Public Class OrderBusiness
        Public Shared Function GetOrder() As Order
            Return New Order() With {
                .CustomerName = "John Doe",
                .DiscountTotal = 100,
                .ReturTotal = 200,
                .OrderDetails = New List(Of OrderDetail)() From {
                    New OrderDetail() With {
                        .ProductName = "Foo",
                        .UnitPrice = 100,
                        .Quantity = 1,
                        .Discount = 0
                    },
                    New OrderDetail() With {
                        .ProductName = "Bar",
                        .UnitPrice = 200,
                        .Quantity = 2,
                        .Discount = 50
                    },
                    New OrderDetail() With {
                        .ProductName = "Baz",
                        .UnitPrice = 50,
                        .Quantity = 3,
                        .Discount = 0
                    }
                }
            }
        End Function
    End Class
Partial Public Class Form1
        Inherits Form

        Public Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()
        End Sub

        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Dim order = OrderBusiness.GetOrder()
            Me.OrderBindingSource.DataSource = order
            Me.OrderDetailBindingSource.DataSource = order.OrderDetails
            Dim p() As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter = {
                New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pCustomerName", order.CustomerName.ToString()),
                New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pDiscountTotal", order.DiscountTotal.ToString()),
                New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pReturTotal", order.ReturTotal.ToString())
            }
            Me.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(p)
            Me.reportViewer1.RefreshReport()
        End Sub
    End Class


result from code

Desired result
sum(Price*Quantity-Discount)-(DiscountTotal+ReturTotal)

=600-(100+200)

TOTAL NET : 300  

